# Azure SQL database says it's full, but contains nothing

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure

Got a database in azure called Logging, which contains a table Log.

`Select count(*) from log`

returns 0

The database is empty.

Attempting to insert says it's full. Azure control panel reports it as being full (more than full, actually), but I don't know why or how to fix it.

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('Logging' , 'MaxSizeInBytes' )`

Returns 1073741824

`SELECT SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8192
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats`

Returns 1081032704

Any ideas? The normal repair commands don't seem to be supported in azure.

Answer (score 1):

First, try issuing a "truncate table log" command and check again. While you're at it, run "select * from sys.all_objects where type = 'U'" to make sure you really have a single table there. Finally, make sure your table has a primary key: tables without primary keys have the bad tendency to grow without limit even if you delete elements (they just mark on ones as deleted and add new ones at the end).